# How to set login session in magento by logging in via code?

Tags: login, rest-api

I am working with the Magento REST API.

I have developed a service for users to sign in, and that works fine.
But when I call the service and try to load the Magento front end, I can't see the logged in user information. User session is not retaining.

I want to use the same user session of the user logged in via REST.

Can any one help me to fix this?

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array("name"=>"frontend"));
$session->login($email, $password);

if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
    $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn( $session->getCustomer() );
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")
                        ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())
                        ->loadByEmail($email);

    if ($customer->getId()) {
        $customerData = $this->_getCustomerDetails($customer);
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->unsCustomerLoginCnt();
    } else {
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.0', Yamaha_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_NOT_FOUND, true);       
        $message = 'Customer Information Currenlty Unavailable';                    
    }
}
```

Comment: it is magento...

Comment: Session sharing is not supported between web APIs and browser in Magento, these are 2 independent sessions.

Answer (score 2):

As Alex mentioned here earlier: Session sharing is not supported between REST and the frontend.

I'm not quite sure where you put the code above and what `unsCustomerLoginCnt` does so you will need to update your question if you still need help.

---

For future readers:

**How to achieve this?**

What needs to be done is to set the session received via REST API as a session cookie with the right domain to the browser. Then you should be able to access that session and be logged in.